# Create slider placeholder to solve anchor issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nivo-slider

I am currently building a site and using the smoothy template located here:
[Smoothy Template](http://www.templatemo.com/live/templatemo_396_smoothy)

If you keep refreshing the site, you'll see the Nivo Slider does not load immediately. This causes all my anchor links to the main page to be thrown off vertically by the same height as the slider images once the Nivo Slider has loaded. I've tried several solutions, such as setting the image height and width manually, and also using a placeholder that fades out once Nivo Slider has loaded, but to no avail.

**Here is my code:**

```
    <div id="sliderwrapper">

    <div  id="slider"  class="nivoSlider templatemo_slider">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/slider/img_1_blank.jpg" width="1050" height="500" alt="slide 1" /></a>             
        <a href="#"><img src="images/slider/img_2_blank.jpg" width="1050" height="500" alt="slide 2" /></a>  
        <a href="#"><img src="images/slider/img_3_blank.jpg" width="1050" height="500" alt="slide 3" /></a>                 
</div>
<div id="preloader" class"nivoSlider templatemo_slider">
<img src="images/preloader.jpg" width="1050" height="500" />
</div>
</div>
```

**And here is my function:**

```
$(window).load(function() {
$('#slider').nivoSlider({
effect:'random', //Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
slices:12,
animSpeed:500, //Slide transition speed
pauseTime:3000,
startSlide:0, //Set starting Slide (0 index)
directionNav:false, //Next & Prev
directionNavHide:true, //Only show on hover
beforeChange: function(){},
afterChange: function(){},
slideshowEnd: function(){}, //Triggers after all slides have been shown
lastSlide: function(){}, //Triggers when last slide is shown
afterLoad: function(){        $('#preloader').fadeOut(500);} //Triggers when slider has loaded

});
});
```

Comment: You can give height to this class 'templatemo_slider'. Once the slider is loaded remove the height.

Comment: You can add image as place holder and give them height and hide it when slider is loaded

Comment: I've successfully added a placeholder which disappears once the slider is loaded and this has solved my anchor problem. However, instead of the slider covering the placeholder, it moves it down the page, which causes the page to jerk down then up. What can I add to css to make them overlap?